# angry ip scanner reports differnet hostname and computer name on a domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain, ip, trace

did a quick sweep of a network this morning and i am getting different hostname to computername in the list.

this is a domain with a DC in there. it has active directory integrated dns.

if you use nslookup to find names there are no issues, but if you do a sweep it has varying computer name to hostname mappings? i have looked under the DC dns forward lookup and things seem fine and no duplicates in there?

can anyone suggest where this issue might come from?
thanks.gd

Comment: did you check reverse entries for the subnet that you scanned?

Comment: good point, do you mean just looking at the reverse dns lookup zone?

Comment: you are right, the reverse lookup has multiple SAME ip to different hostname? how come? is there a setting i can change or scavenge? thaks

Comment: on the general tab in the properties of the zone, you can adjust the aging and scavenging details.

Comment: did that and forced a scavenge of stale records with not much luck any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS scavenging does not affect manually created DNS records, only dynamic DNS records. You probably want to go in and clean up the reverse lookup zone by hand (assuming that the incorrect records were added manually to the forward lookup zone).

Comment: actually i think the problem is that there was a second DC in a remote site, the vpn tunnel has stopped working since there was an issue with the server adn it was taken offline in the remote site but never dcpromo demoted. If there are records, which there are, in the Active Directory Sites and Services, is there a best practice to clean up the remote site subnet? I want to remove the old second DC and i guess do a ntdsutil metadata cleanup. Any suggestions? I think that the main DC is trying to replicate the forward and reverse DNS and maybe not scavenging due to it waitiing on the second dc

Comment: the second DC is the one that no longer exists due to the vpn tunnel and the fact that the tech has wiped it and made it just a stand alone server there.